# Upload files using Vuejs with Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

I work in the project with vuejs and bootsrapt-vue and I want to upload any type of file(picture, pdf ..etc) by axios library.
When I try to upload, nothing is uploading to the backend. Can some one please look in my code and tell what I'm doing wrong?
I'm pretty new into coding.

Here is my code:

```
`

<template> <b-container fluid>
        <h4>Images page</h4>

        <!-- <b-form-file action="" v-model="image" plain></b-form-file> -->
       <b-form action="" method="post" v-model="image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2>Select image to upload:</h2>

            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

            <b-button type="submit" name="submit" variant="success" v-on:click="uploadImage">Upload image</b-button>
        </b-form>
    </b-container>
</template>



<script>
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    /* eslint-disable */
    export default {
        name: 'imagesPage',
        data() {
            return {
                images: [],
                image: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            uploadImage(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault()
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('image', document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0])
                var token = sessionStorage.setItem('token', data, null)
                window.API.post('https://192.168.56.101:8080/images/' + token, data, null)
                .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data);

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                    })
                console.log('blabla')
                //         this.template.push({
                //         image_id: ''
                // })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`

Comment: Do you get any kind of response from the server? Go to `Networking` tab in your dev tools and click on the request that you're sending.

Comment: yes, it says: token = undefined.   https://192.168.56.101:8080/images?token=

Comment: i have to do something whit the token but i don't know what....

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with the token but you should be authing into the app itself. If possible, try adding your token directly into the variable, e.g.: `var token = the_token_you_are_missing`. Because currently you are just setting a session storage object whose `key` value is named `token` and the data that you are passing is the whole form data object. You need a proper token to proceed uploading.

Comment: look here, it might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqnJwh6E9ak

Comment: thanks mate...helped me.